# How to fix corrupt git remote repo

Tags: git, github

When pulling this remote repo

```
git pull https://github.com/axsuul/cookbook-database
```

there appears to be a corrupt index file.

```
git cat-file -t 244eacec46c81c1b308c2e968805020313d0e214
```

returns

```
fatal: git cat-file 244eacec46c81c1b308c2e968805020313d0e214: bad file
```

What could be causing this and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

- if someone else has the repository you can clone it for him.
- if you dont have a copy of the repository you can still "digg" into the .git folder and find the bad file and replace it with the latest OK version. to do it you will need access to the git repository. execute: `git fsck` and paste the results here.

Im sorry that i cant help you more then that, in order to fix it i will need access to the repository itself.

Try to find out which file is it and then replace it with a previous version, you will lose that latest changes but your repository will be be usable again.

Comment: Thanks, I've added you as a contributor